Flatten or melt nested column headers in a .csv using pandas
I need to turn a .csv table that includes nested tables with their own column headers into a normalized structure where nested column headers are brought out into a standard column. As an example, I need the original csv with first row headers shown below:
ID1,ID2,Result1,Result2,Result3
US,PA,5,,
US,FL,3,,
US,CA,Year,Value1,Value2
US,CA,1997,1,2
US,CA,1999,3,4
US,CA,2000,5,6
FR,,9,,
UK,,Color,Num1,Num2
UK,,Red,10%,11%
UK,,Blue,13%,2%
UK,,Green,5%,6%
Transformed into the one below where the nested column headers (here simply shown as the first row in a specific ID1/ID2 combination subtable) are extracted into a new column as shown:
ID1,ID2,Result1,Result2,Result3,Nested_Col_Header
US,PA,5,,,
US,FL,3,,,
US,CA,Year,Value1,Value2
US,CA,1997,,,Year
US,CA,1999,,,Year
US,CA,2000,,,Year
US,CA,,1,,Value1
US,CA,,3,,Value1
US,CA,,5,,Value1
US,CA,,,2,Value2
US,CA,,,4,Value2
US,CA,,,6,Value2
FR,,9,,,
UK,,Color,Num1,Num2
UK,,Red,,,Color
UK,,Blue,,,Color
UK,,Green,,,Color
UK,,,10%,,Num1
UK,,,13%,,Num1
UK,,,5%,,Num1
UK,,,,11%,Num2
UK,,,,2%,Num2
UK,,,,6%,Num2
I'm bringing the csv into pandas as a dataframe with the first row becoming the column names in the dataframe (using read_csv with no parameters other than the csv file name). I can segment out the subtables based on the ID1/ID2 combination for the additional processing and rebuild a new table appending the various subtables together, but I can't solve for how to pull the nested column headers out and lengthen the table.
I've tried combinations of stack and melt functions with multiIndex (one of which I suspect is the right answer), but I'm not sufficiently familiar with pandas to know how to bring the pieces together. I know I could brute force this with some nasty loops, but I expect there is a clean piece of code that could resolve this very easily.
